# Jenkins Job is failing even PS script is successfully executed

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0

I have below script which will

Stop WebService

Delete WebService

Copy items from Jenkins workspace to server path

Create WebService

Start WebService

I run this PS script in Jenkins job and after execution of this,I get a email as Build is failed.

```
val STOPPED
[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
val DELETED
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item \\Location.dll: Access to the 
path '\\Location.dll' is denied.
At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson7587011077362516847.ps1:33 char:5
+     Remove-Item "$val\*" -Force -Recurse
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\10.0.1.190\d$...h\Grpc.Core.dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], Unauthoriz 
   edAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

My PS script

```
# force strict - so any variable used before being assigned causes an error
Set-PsDebug -Strict

# force PowerShell to exit with a non-zero code on teh first error
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# set $LASTEXITCODE to zero, so the script doesn't fail if no exit code returned
$LASTEXITCODE = 0

# set directories here once, so we can reuse
$MystiflySearchDir = "\\Location"
$ReleaseDir   = "C:\Location"

# get directory contents (are you expecting these to return to Jenkins?)
Get-ChildItem "$ReleaseDir\*"

# create the search directory if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $val -PathType Container)) { New-Item -Path $val-type directory -Force }

# get the service, but fail gracefully if it doesn't exist
$service = Get-Service -Name val -Computername $env:SERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# if we have a service, stop and delete it
if($service.Status)
{
    sc.exe \\$env:SERVER stop val 
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error stopping the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
    Write-Host "val STOPPED"
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    sc.exe \\$env:SERVER delete val
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error deleting the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
    Write-Host "val DELETED"
    Start-Sleep -s 25
    Remove-Item "$val\*" -Force -Recurse
}

# copy release to search
xcopy "$ReleaseDir\*" $val/k/e/d/Y

# (re)create the service
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER create val start=auto DisplayName= "value"  binPath= D:\Location.exe
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error creating the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER description val "val"
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error adding description to service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER start val
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error starting the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
Write-Host "val STARTED"
```

Is there anything i am missing here

Comment: well, if you are completely sure it doesnt do `exit 1` some other step is failing the build job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code needed a little tidying up, as you had a couple of repeating sections, that were performed whether the service existed or not. Also flipped the if logic.

Added some steps at the start of your code to cause PowerShell to be more strict and drop out on any errors with a non-zero code.

This has not been tested, so may need a little fine-tuning. However, it should be 95% there, hopefully!

```
# force strict - so any variable used before being assigned causes an error
Set-PsDebug -Strict
# force PowerShell to exit with a non-zero code on the first error
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# set $LASTEXITCODE to zero, so the script doesn't fail if no exit code returned
$LASTEXITCODE = 0

# se directories her once, so we can reuse
$AirSearchDir = "\\Location"
$ReleaseDir   = "C:\Location"

# get directory contents (are you expecting these to return to Jenkins?)
Get-ChildItem "$ReleaseDir\*"

# create the search directory if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $AirSearchDir -PathType Container)) { New-Item -Path $AirSearchDir -type directory -Force }

# get the service, but fail gracefully if it doesn't exist
$service = Get-Service -Name val -Computername $env:SERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# if we have a service, stop and delete it
if($service.Status)
{
    sc.exe \\$env:SERVER stop val 
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error stopping the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
    Write-Host "val STOPPED"
    sc.exe \\$env:SERVER delete val 
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error deleting the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
    Write-Host "val DELETED"
}

# copy release to search
Copy-Item "$ReleaseDir\*" $AirSearchDir -Force -Recurse

# (re)create the service
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER create val start=auto DisplayName="val"  binPath= D:\Location.exe
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error creating the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER description val "val"
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error adding description to service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
sc.exe \\$env:SERVER start val
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { throw "error starting the service: $LASTEXITCODE" }
Write-Host "val STARTED"
```

Comment: I see below error.
The variable '$LastExitCode' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson242794619230845253.ps1:32 char:6
+ exit $LastExitCode
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (LastExitCode:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined

Comment: I get this error all time when I execute this error. Am I missing amything more. see the edited code and error

Comment: Sorry, haven't used Jenkins. You need to run the script outside of Jenkins, in PowerShell_ISE. Add a breakpoiont at the first command, then F10 to step through the code to figure out which line is causing the error. See this MSDN article on debugging: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise

Comment: Using below step we are getting the service but if it does not exist we re not failing.

# get the service, but fail gracefully if it doesn't exist
$service = Get-Service -Name AirSearchWindowsService -Computername $env:SERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Comment: Depends on what conditions you want to fail. Your logic says to create the service if it doesn't exist and remove it if it does. If you want to fail when the service doesn't exist add else logic after the `if { ...}` - `else { throw "service does not exist" }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136217/discussion-between-bhave-and-techspud).

Answer (score 0):

Try running your Jenkins with the administrator account, the reason why you are getting this error is because your jenkins user is unable to interact with the services.

Running it with the administrator account will give it sufficient privileges to interact with other services.